# MySQL Getting a daily average of last 2 records grouped by user

Tags: mysql

i have a MySQL table like the following:

```
PKey  ReadID  UserID  Date        Used
   1  abc        101  2015-02-01   553
   2  abc        102  2015-02-01  1090
   3  abc        103  2015-05-01   640
   4  def        104  2015-06-01   140
   5  ghi        101  2015-07-01   780
   6  ghi        102  2015-07-01  2108
   7  ghi        103  2015-07-01   778
   8  jkl        104  2015-12-07   198
   9  jkl        105  2015-12-07   101
  10  jkl        102  2015-12-07  2500
  11  jkl        103  2015-12-07   898
```

So what im trying to end up with a daily average `Used` for a particular `ReadID`, grouped by the `UserID`. 
For example, to end up with the below output for `ReadID` = jkl

```
            UserID      Daily Avg

            102         2.465
            103         0.754
            104         0.306
            105         n/a
```

If i use the above table, the calculation for `UserID` = 102 with `ReadID` = jkl is:
`select (2500 - 2108 ) / DateDiff ('2015-12-07', '2015-07-01')`
This gives an answer of 2.465

These figures come from:
`select (current Used - last previous Used ) / DateDiff('current Date', 'last previous Date')`

So I can do it for one `UserID` at a time , but not for all the `UserID` in a particular `ReadID`.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I think there is some confusion between userID and readID

Comment: @O. Jones  Apologies,that was the wrong set of values.I have put the correct values for the example in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below for a few `ReadID` and it seems to be working :

```
SELECT  x.MeterID,(x.Used - y.lastused) / DATEDIFF( x.date, y.lastdate) AS dailyavg 
    FROM
        (SELECT PKey,ReadID,UserID, Date AS date,Used
            FROM table1
            WHERE ReadID = 'jkl') x
    JOIN
        (SELECT MAX(PKey) lastpkey,ReadID,MeterID,MAX(Date) AS lastdate,Max(Used) AS lastused
            FROM table1
            WHERE Date < (select MIN(Date) FROM table1 WHERE ReadID = 'jkl')
            GROUP BY MeterID 
            Order BY Date DESC ) y
    ON y.MeterID = x.MeterID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are functions that allow you to take the average of given values, and there are clauses that allow you to Group aggregated information (like averages) according to other values. Given that, try something like this:

`SELECT AVG(Used) FROM [table] WHERE date = [date] GROUP BY UserID`

Also, I recommend you take a look at the [MySQL 5.7 Reference Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html). This link has information on GROUP BY functions, and you can find information on averages if you look a little bit.